# Are these equivalent? $\cos^2(5x) = (\cos(5x))^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry, convention

Are these equivalent?

$$\cos^2(5x) = (\cos(5x))^2$$

Comment: Yes. In mathematics, the first is standard.

Comment: Carl Gauss (the most famous person to live on Earth in the 19th century, except for those who did not work in the physical and mathematical sciences) felt strongly that $\cos^2(x)$ ought to mean $\cos(\cos(x))$, but by his time it had become standard that $\cos^2x$ means $(\cos x)^2$, and so it has remained. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy,  do you have a reference for that story?

Comment: Good question, but a hard one $\ldots$

Comment: @abel : $\ldots\ldots$ um $\ldots\ldots$ I $\ldots$ read it somewhere. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I think we all (or most of us) would agree that it'd be better if $\cos^2(x)$ meant $\cos(\cos(x))$, but we'd have to fight hundreds of years of convention.  And it's not such a big deal, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $\cos^n(x) = (\cos(x))^n$. This is true for all of the trigonometric functions, but these are actually special cases. Often, the notation $f^n(x)$ means
$$
(f\underbrace{\circ \cdots \circ}_{\text{$n$ times}}f)(x).
$$